# JQM show next page using .next()

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

My script looks something like this :

```
if(e.keyCode==13){
    if(input == answer){

      alert('Right answer');
      $.mobile.changePage( "#pagetwo", { transition: "flow", changeHash: false });
    }
}
```

My question is if I can change the pages without having to use id's for it, I don't need prev navigation, just for the next page and the above script is part of a larger one that applies for all pages so I would hate to believe I will have to duplicate the above for each page.

**So...**
How can I change the page to next one on enter without having to write the id for each page added?

PS, please don't hate me for being new to JQM, thanks :D

---

### UPDATE WITH A SOLUTION

Based on @ezanker's suggestion I came up with this solution:
Also, if there is a better way of doing this, please post an answer.

```
if ($.mobile.activePage.next("[data-role=page]").length !== 0) {
            var next = $.mobile.activePage.next("[data-role=page]");
            $.mobile.changePage(next, {
                 transition: 'slide'
            });
            }
```

Comment: Have a look at the next() method in jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/next/)  Get the active page and then call  .next('[data-role="page"]') to get the next page div in the dom.

Comment: @ezanker Made an update with a working example based on your suggestion :D Thanks :D works like a charm